# Value returned from setup is not reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```
import { onMounted, onUpdated, readonly } from "vue";
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  setup(props) {
    let myMsg = null;
    onMounted(() => (myMsg = props.msg));
    onUpdated(() => (myMsg = "bar"));
    console.log(myMsg); // null 

    return { myMsg };
  },
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-river-d49em?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Not just that the `myMsg` is not reactive but it stays unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable in setup needs to be `ref` to be reactive. You can check more about vue3 composition api [here](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html#setup-component-option):

```js
setup(props) {
  let myMsg = ref(null);
  onMounted(() => (myMsg.value = props.msg));
  onUpdated(() => (myMsg.value = "bar"));
  console.log(myMsg.value); // null 

  return { myMsg };
},
```

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-yalow-sr9gn?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)